# Are there several others saiyans alive?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-minus

In the anime Vegeta insisted the only saiyans alive were him, Nappa, Raditz, Goku and Goku's son Gohan. Later we found out that Vegeta's brother Tarble was alive (in the case this is canon, by the way, Vegeta never mentioned him before) and recently that Broly and his father Paragus too. But in Dragon Ball Minus which seems to be canon

> Freezer asks to one of his soldiers before killing all the saiyans how many saiyans returned to Planet Vegeta, his soldier replies most of them should be back in a month or so but it will take a little longer for every single saiyan to come back, and Freezer says he cannot wait that long, he will execute his plan in a month's time.

Does this mean there are several others saiyans alive?

Comment: We are only talking about the main Universe that the previous series are in right (ie. Dragonball Z)? because in other Universes (shown in Super) there are other Seiyan like Caulifla and Kale

Comment: Not counting the other universes. In the original universe

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Answer found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dbz/comments/1avkcw/dbz_there_are_thousands_of_saiyans_left_in_the/). I take no credit in writing this. I just found out that both the question and the answer in this link answers this question.</sup>

- **Argument**

> Throughout DBZ there is a running gag of Vegeta saying "I am the
> Prince of all Saiyans" despite us only seeing a handful in series and
> movies (Goku, Bardock, Borgos, Broly, Fasha, King Vegeta, Nappa,
> Paragus, Raditz, Tarble, Tora, Turles, Vegeta, Bulla, Gohan, Goten,
> Pan, Trunks). Along with the notion that the Saiyan race is pretty
> much extinct except for the main characters. But this is wrong and not
> plausible given what the Saiyans' role was under Frieza.
>
> So the Saiyan-Tuffle war ends in the Age of 730. At this point in
> their history the Saiyans are just brutes with no technology until the
> Arcosians arrive and trade technology in exchange for them conquering
> planets. Shortly after seeing how good Saiyans are at fighting/killing
> they are annexed under Frieza and his Planet Trade Organization in the
> Age of 731 and become part of his military. And let’s assume it takes
> about a year for the planet to be fully developed as seen in the
> flashbacks and in the movie Bardock- The Father of Goku. So the planet
> is all up and running in the Age of 732.
>
> So Frieza has the Saiyans doing his dirty work conquering planets
> across the universe for himself or for sale. His need/demand/want is
> so great that the Saiyans send their babies to planets with weak
> inhabitants to conquer. This continues until Frieza destroys the
> planet in the Age of 737. So for 5 years the Saiyans are sending their
> young to the ends of the universe for Frieza. Now the only question is
> how many are being sent daily. In the movie Bardock- The Father of
> Goku you can see a long hallway where the space pods are where the
> babies are sent out. From the scene you can see ~14 pods from the two
> sides and we can safely assume [the hallway has
> more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Nxf.jpg). And in the movie Broly- The
> Legendary Super Saiyan you get a better look at the nursery and you
> see [~8 beds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hawW1.png) with babies and again we
> can assume there are more.
>
> So the Saiyans had no problems sending their babies to these planets
> because any babies that were decently strong would stay on the planet
> to be raised as elites. The weak are sent away with no exception e.g.
> Tarble was sent away for being too weak despite being from Royal
> blood. In episode 124 "Z Warriors Prepare" King Vegeta says to Vegeta
> "The weakest of our people are sent to planets far away, where they
> face no threat from our enemies" while standing in front of a window
> pointing out the spacepods (carrying babies) leaving the planet. In
> the scene you can see [~60 spacepods
> leaving](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqyMBw3TRpY). And let's assume
> this happens at least once a week and that Planet Vegeta's year is
> similar to Earth since the whole series refers to time the same way
> the Earth does.
>
> So considering all this you have:
>
> 60 Saiyans sent out weekly every year over 5 years
>
> 60x52x5 = 15600 Saiyans in the Universe
>
> And what happens after Frieza destroys Planet Vegeta? He lies about
> what happened to cover his tracks telling people that a comet
> destroyed the planet. He doesn't bother hunting down and killing the
> remaining Saiyans because he killed the strongest of them on the
> planet with the exception of Vegeta, Nappa, and Raditz. The weakest
> ones are of no threat to him and scattered across the universe (except
> Goku). And everyone pretty much accepts this, even Raditz is under the
> impression that is how things happened stating in the second episode
> "3 years ago, our planet was destroyed by meteorites". And of the
> Saiyans that were sent some were female, since all Saiyans love to
> fight and women did help conquer planets as well (Fasha a female
> Saiyan was on Bardock's team). The Saiyan race is alive and well, just
> separated by a distance.

- **Opinion**

I think there are definitely more Saiyans around but I imagined after Frieza destroyed the planet, teams were sent to find remnants of the race. Like when they defeated Bardock's group but looking for lost Saiyan children instead. Some were found, some were not (like Goku).

There are definitely more out there but most are probably too distant to come across. It does leave things open ended for more Saiyan encounters.

I would also think that there are a lot of hybrids out there. I have a feeling saiyans weren't taking a moral high ground about rape.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

We should probably assume there are no more Saiyans in Universe 7 until Toriyama (or someone else) decides to pull more out of a hat. [Vegeta's brother](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Tarble) was a huge stretch. He was attested to nowhere previously, up until *The Return of Son Goku and Friends* special. The same can be said of [Bulma's sister](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Tights), who first appeared in *Jaco the Galactic Patrolman*. These were retcons that clashed with previous canon. Nevertheless, these stories are now canon, and these two are now both seen or referenced in *Dragon Ball Super*, so we must accept them as canon. And there is at least a somewhat plausible explanation for why Tarble is alive (though not for why Vegeta never mentioned him), as seen [here](https://en.dragon-ball-official.com/news/01_1428.html#:%7E:text=Tarble%20is%20a%20Saiyan%20from,banished%20to%20a%20distant%20planet.):

> Tarble is a Saiyan from Planet Vegeta and, shockingly, Vegeta's
> younger brother. At a young age, he was deemed unsuited for combat and
> conquest by King Vegeta and banished to a distant planet.
> Mild-mannered and possessed of a soft demeanor, Tarble has the
> polar-opposite personality to that of his arrogant and battle-hungry
> older brother.

### Canon Issues

The destruction of the Saiyan race is important in the original fight against Frieza. Goku and/or Vegeta say stuff about the Saiyans having paid for their sins, and how Goku will be the only Saiyan left when Vegeta dies, so he has to avenge them against Frieza. And we are told in no uncertain terms, from the very start of *Dragon Ball Z*, that only Goku, Vegeta, Raditz, and Nappa survived the purge.

As far as *Dragon Ball Minus goes*, I reviewed the page for it on the Fandom Wiki and saw some panels of it; it would seem that the order to return to Planet Vegeta reached even children:

[image: Raditz and Vegeta]

It probably wouldn't have been typical for them to ignore the order in the manner Vegeta does. Whether they got back in the one month time limit Frieza gave, they would probably still get eliminated when they showed up.

Additionally, this seems to have canon discrepancies. I noticed Goku wearing Saiyan armor in a picture, but the [Wiki](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Minus:_The_Departure_of_the_Fated_Child) does a better job at listing out some additional details I didn't notice, so I'll quote it:

> The manga's depiction of Goku greatly contrasts to the TV special Dragon Ball Z: Bardock - The Father of Goku. In this story, Goku's age at the time of Planet Vegeta's destruction is different than in other media: he is three years old, in contrast to a few days old. In Minus, Goku is also clothed in Saiyan gear, while in other depictions he isn't. These changes are likely in part due to Bardock - The Father of Goku being the kind of story Akira Toriyama "absolutely wouldn't draw".

At the end of the day, *Dragon Ball* stepped all over its own canon, which is pretty typical for a long-running series. And there were definitely tonal shifts from *Dragon Ball* to *Dragon Ball Z* and then again to *Dragon Ball Super*, as well as many retcons. I don't think we can conclude anything; we just have to wait and see whether the story decides more Saiyans need to be pulled out of that hat and put into the story (maybe even grab a whole planet of them from another [universe](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Universe_6)).

### List of Saiyans Known to Have Survived the Purge

**Definitely Canonical** (in no particular order, and crossed out if they are no longer alive)

1. Goku
2. Vegeta
3. <s>Raditz</s>
4. <s>Nappa</s>
5. Tarble
6. Broly
7. <s>Paragus</s>

Additionally, two unknown Saiyans are seen with Vegeta in the Broly movie, though they most likely died at some point afterwards. Picture and quote from here: https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Genocide_of_the_Saiyans

[image: Unknown Saiyans]

> In Dragon Ball Super: Broly, two adult Saiyans also survive due to being on assignment with Young Vegeta, Nappa, and Young Raditz. However, it is unknown what happens to them after.

**Half-Saiyans/Quarter-Saiyans**

1. Gohan
2. Trunks
3. Goten
4. Bulla
5. Pan

**Semi-canonical**

1. <s>Turles</s>

**Questionable/Non-canonical**

1. Onio (From *Neko Majin*, which is probably not canonical)

Partially pieced together from looking through this: https://dragonballencyclopedia.com/wiki/List_of_Saiyans

And cross-referenced with this https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Genocide_of_the_Saiyans:

> Only nine pure Saiyans are confirmed to have survived by the time of the Raditz Saga: Goku, Broly, Tarble, Vegeta, Raditz, Nappa, Turles, Paragus and Onio. The two unnamed male survivors presumably having perished prior.